# sizeof argv[1] not working

Tags: c, sizeof

I'm really new to C and all I know is that the error is related to `oldname` and `newname` not be initialized

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int result;
    int lengthOne;
    int lengthTwo;
    lengthOne = sizeof(argv[0]);
    lengthTwo= sizeof(argv[1]);

    char oldname[lengthOne] = argv[0];
    char newname[lengthOne] = argv[1];

    result = rename(oldname, newname);

    if (result == 0) {
        puts "File renamed";
    } else {
        perror "ERROR: Could not rename file";
    }

    return 0;
}

app.c: In function ‘main’:
app.c:11: error: variable-sized object may not be initialized
app.c:12: error: variable-sized object may not be initialized
app.c:17: error: expected ‘;’ before string constant
app.c:19: error: expected ‘;’ before string constant
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
lengthOne = sizeof(argv[0]);
lengthTwo= sizeof(argv[1]);
```

This gives you the size of a `char*`, **not** the length of the string.  You meant `strlen`, not `sizeof`.

```
char oldname[lengthOne] = argv[0];
char newname[lengthOne] = argv[1];
```

You can't assign to arrays like that.  You could `strcpy` them, but it's unnecessary here because you can just use pointers.

```
const char* oldname = argv[0];
const char* newname = argv[1]; // But verify that argc >= 2 first!
```

**EDIT**: Also, don't forget that `argv[0]` is the name of the program itself, and `argv[1]` is the first argument.  If your intent was to write a `mv`-like program instead of a program that renames itself, you want `argv[1]` and `argv[2]`.

Comment: The problem stems from the confusion due to the correlation between arrays and pointers, and specifically in relation to string constants. You can say `char str[]="blah"; int i=sizeof(str);` to get 5, so it’s not unreasonable to expect argv to work the same since it is an array that is filled out before the program even runs and not a dynamically allocated block of memory assigned to a pointer. Of course Tony’s explanation of how `sizeof` is a compile-time construct helps make it clear, but that is not obvious when a novice learns by viewing code instead of reading books.

Answer (score 5):

You seem to not be understanding what pointers are in C. This is a very core concept that you need to understand to be able to use the language.

I would start with a tutorial on them. A guick google brings this up as the first result: http://pw1.netcom.com/~tjensen/ptr/pointers.htm

Answer (score 1):

First, `char x[length] = /* something */;` only works for string literals (i.e. `"string"` or `{'s', 't', 'r', 'i', 'n', 'g', '\0'}` if you want to be masochistic).

Second, to call a function, use parenthesis. `puts("Text");` and `printf("Text\n");`. They are not optional like they are in some languages.

Third, as a function parameter (even if it's a parameter to `main()`), an array type decays to a pointer. So your function signature is effectively `int main(int argc, char **argv)` (and I prefer to write it that way, personally, but it makes no difference). You can't take the `sizeof` an array that has decayed to a pointer because it's not an array anymore and has no associated information about it's size. To get the size, use `strlen()`.

Fourth, use a `size_t` to store sizes. Using an `int` to store sizes is wrong - there's no guarantee that `int` is large enough to hold sizes, and you can't have a -5 sized object of any kind. `size_t` is an unsigned integral type included in the standard for precisely this purpose.

Lastly, if you need a object whose size depends on runtime conditions, you can't use an array. You have to use a pointer, and use `malloc` to create a block of memory of the correct size, and then use `free` to destroy it when you're done. EDIT: Or just assign `argv[0]` to the pointer. `argv` is guaranteed in the standard to be writable, so you can edit it (just try to avoid appending anything).

Answer (score 1):

sizeof is a compile-time check... the sizeof any argv element will be the number of bytes in a pointer-to-char.  It has nothing to do with the run-time length of the text that pointer may address: `strlen()` returns that.  But, C doesn't let you create dynamically (i.e. runtime) sized arrays.  And even then you can't copy a string into another string with `=`... it requires a call to `strcpy(dest, src)`.  To make it work, obviously the easiest thing is:

```
result = rename(argv[0], argv[1])
```

But, I appreciate you're trying to learn how to copy the values into your own buffer.  To do so, you need to dynamically create a sufficiently large buffer (memory-allocate or `malloc`), string-copy it, use it then `free` it.  Several of these requirements are satisfied by the `strdup()` function:

```
const char* p_old_name = strdup(argv[0]);
const char* p_new_name = strdup(argv[1]);
rename(p_old_name, p_new_name);
free(p_old_name);
free(p_new_name);
```

Alternatively, you can statically specify a maximum size for the two strings (dangerous if you get it wrong - strncpy() can provide a more safety but a mistake may still prevent your program working with some long-but-valid paths):

```
#include <linux/limit.h>   // or wherever you can find PATH_MAX or similar
...

char old_name[PATH_MAX];
char new_name[PATH_MAX];
strcpy(old_name, argv[0]);
strcpy(new_name, argv[1]);
rename(old_name, new_name);
```

Note: as `argv[0]` is the program name, this program changes it's own executable name to whatever the second argument is.  If you want it to change another file's name, then you should use `argv[0]` and `argv[1]`.

Comment: Not all systems have `strdup`, but it's simple enough to implement on your own and convenient enough to be useful that whenever I point out this technicality I also include a complete and correct implementation of the function for the rare platform where it is lacking: `char *strdup(const char *c) { size_t l = strlen(c) + 1; char *p = malloc(l); if(p) memcpy(p, c, l); return p; }`

Answer (score 0):

sizeof() returns the size of the type - ie the size of a pointer (probably 32bits) or a char (8bits)
To get the length of a string you need strlen()

Additionally in ansi C you can't create an array with a variable for the size. You can in the new C standard or for now you can use malloc() to create an array

Answer (score 0):

`argv` is of the type `char*[]`, i.e., an array of pointers to char.  Thus, any first level element will simply be a `char*` and, as such, sizeof(argv[i]) will always return the native pointer size.  You need to use strlen or some equivalent function to get the length of the string.